# Count number of users in AD group using dsget group

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm trying to get a number count of the number of active users in an AD group. Through research I've been using `dsget group "CN=xx,OU=xx,OU=xx,OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=net" -members -expand` in PowerShell and that returns a list of users which i'm then copying out into Notepadd++ to count the line number amount for my count.

Is there a way to just return a count number of users rather than the list and also excluded any disabled users?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe any output from your powershell cli dsquery/dsget to Measure-Object for a quick count;

> dsget group "CN=xx,OU=xx,OU=xx,OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=net" -members
>   -expand -limit xxxx | dsget user -disabled | find " yes" | Measure-Object

Will provide output similar to the following;

```
Count    : xx
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

Hope this helps.